# Get All Blobs From Memory JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory, blob

Blobs are stored in memory. If I created 6 blobs, then they are stored in memory. Lets say that they cannot be assigned a url or be set as a variable or anything similar to that. How might they be accessed? I simply don't know how to do this. I would like to be able to end up with an array of all the blobs that were created on this page.

```js
new Blob(['blob1'], {type: 'text/plain'});
new Blob(['blob2'], {type: 'text/plain'});
new Blob(['blob3'], {type: 'text/plain'});
new Blob(['blob4'], {type: 'text/plain'});
new Blob(['blob5'], {type: 'text/plain'});
new Blob(['blob6'], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

I would like to know how I can get the following result the result:

```js
function getBlobs() {
   //This is fake code
   return Blobs.allBlobs;
}
console.log(getBlobs()) //Result would be the blobs
```

Comment: This looks like some kind of hypothetical code. Where's the definition of the "Blob" class?  Ignoring that for a moment, why can't you push each new Blob onto an array and use that to track "all blobs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now learned that if the blobs are created without any reference to them i.e. they are not assigned `var`, `let`, `const` or a url, they will be stored in memory until they are collected by the `garbage collector`. There is no way to access these blobs without hypothetically going into the browsers temporary folder.
**TL;DR**
You cannot do what the question asks.